How can I stop the texture stretching when randomly scaling Instance on points in geometry nodes?
How can I stop the texture stretching when randomly scaling Instance on points in geometry nodes?
I am creating a city with randomly sized buildings. The tall buildings are getting stretched textures.
I have tried a few things seen in some videos but nothings working for me.
Has anyone any experience with this?
Thank you.

Are these textures added by UV? Object? Generated? Another method?

You might try to add the texture via geometry nodes on each instance, considering the scale in mapping.
